# How to scrape through search results spanning multiple pages with lxml

Tags: python-2.7, web-scraping, lxml, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm using lxml to scrape through a site. I want to scrape through a search result, that contains 194 items. My scraper is able to scrape only the first page of search results. How can I scrape the rest of the search results?

```
url = 'http://www.alotofcars.com/new_car_search.php?pg=1&byshowroomprice=0.5-500&bycity=Gotham'
response_object = requests.get(url)

# Build DOM tree
dom_tree = html.fromstring(response_object.text)
```

After this there are scraping functions

```
def enter_mmv_in_database(dom_tree,engine):
# Getting make, model, variant
name_selector = CSSSelector('[class="secondary-cell"] p a')
name_results = name_selector(dom_tree)
for n in name_results:
    mmv = str(`n.text_content()`).split('\\xa0')
    make,model,variant = mmv[0][2:], mmv[1], mmv[2][:-2]
    # Now push make, model, variant in Database
    print make,model,variant
```

By looking at the list I receive I can see that only the first page of search results is parsed. How can I parse the whole of search result.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to navigate through that website but it seems to be offline. Yet, I would like to help with the logic.

What I usually do is:

1. Make a request to the search URL (with parameters filled)
2. With lxml, extract the **last** page available number in a pagination div.
3. **Loop** from first page to the last one, making requests and scraping desired data:

   ```
   for page_number in range(1, last+1):
       ## make requests replacing 'page_number' in 'pg' GET variable
       url = "http://www.alotofcars.com/new_car_search.php?pg={}&byshowroomprice=0.5-500&bycity=Gotham'".format(page_number)            
       response_object = requests.get(url)
       dom_tree = html.fromstring(response_object.text)
       ...
       ...
   ```

I hope this helps. Let me know if you have any further questions.